# Android OnClickListner is not called on Button click

Tags: android, button, dialog, listener

An intent for an Activity (RluSvcMenu) is fired from a Service when a user clicks on the Notification item.  RluSvcMenu then successfully displays a custom dialog box with three option buttons (Copy/Next; Next; Quit).  All is well, except that when any of the three buttons is clicked, the Listener function does not seem to be called.  Here are the pertinent parts of the RluSvcMenu code:

```
package com.lovelady.android.RluApp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RluSvcMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private int action;
    private Button btnCopyNext;
private Button btnNext;
    private Button btnQuit;
private final int SVC_MENU_DIALOG = 1;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private final String MY_TAG = "RluSvcMenu";
    private final String MESSAGE1 = "onCreate message";
    private final String MESSAGE2 = "onPrepare message";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  showDialog(SVC_MENU_DIALOG);
  Log.d(MY_TAG, "showDialog() has completed.");
}


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rlu_service_menu);

        dialog.setTitle("RLU_APP");

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(MESSAGE1);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rlu);

    btnCopyNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.BtnCopyNext);
    btnCopyNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.BtnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnQuit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.BtnQuit);
    btnQuit.setOnClickListener(this);
    return dialog;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    action = v.getId() ;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
            , "Button " + action + " clicked."
            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(MY_TAG, "Button " + action + " clicked.");
    dialog.dismiss();
}


protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rlu_service_menu);

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(MESSAGE2);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_rlu_app);
}
}
```

The XML to build the "service menu" is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="4dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnCopyNext"
        android:text="Copy/Next"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BtnCopyNext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnNext"
        android:text="Next"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BtnNext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/BtnQuit"
        android:text="Quit"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

... and finally, the AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.lovelady.android.AppName"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_mainIcon">
        <activity android:name=".RluSvcMenu"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".RluOverview"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to RluSearch -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value=".RluSearch" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RluDetails"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".RluImportFile"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".RluImportFilteredFile"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".RluSearch">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".RluManager"
                 android:exported="false"
                 android:label="@string/service_name">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

What might cause touches to not be delivered to the Activity?  Are they going to the service instead?  If so, what can I do to get focus?  (I thought I'd get focus by putting up the dialog, but the only clue I have, from logcat, indicates:

```
07-09 21:04:20.060 I/InputDispatcher(  302): Delivering touch to current input \
                   target: action: 0, channel '409079b8 Rluapp (server)'
```

(where "Rluapp" is the value of @string/my_app, and the name of the package)

... or what hole did I forget to fill in my Listener?  For all intents and purposes "nothing" happens when the buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I suspect the dialog is running in a different thread?  Well anyway if you use one and alert dialog they have DialogInterface.onClickListener class that handles that, there may be a better way to overcome the problem, but changing the code to and actual custom dialog fixes this.

Here is your original code modified with that fix, this is probably better anyway since you can then put the dialog in it's own file/class etc.

```
public class BtnNoWorky extends Activity {
    private int action;
    private Button btnCopyNext;
    private Button btnNext;
    private Button btnQuit;
    private final int SVC_MENU_DIALOG = 1;
    private final String MY_LABEL = "BtnNoWorky";
    private final String MESSAGE1 = "Msg from onCreateDialog";
    private final String MESSAGE2 = "Msg from onPrepare";
    private myDialog D = null; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(MY_LABEL, "Show dialog") ;
        //showDialog(SVC_MENU_DIALOG);
        D = new myDialog(this);
        D.show();

        Log.d(MY_LABEL, "showDialog() has completed.");
    }

    public class myDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

    public myDialog(Context context) {
            super(context,0);
    }

    public myDialog(Context context, int theme) {
            super(context, theme);
    }

    protected myDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable, OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
            super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    public void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - Creating dialog");

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - setContentView");
        setContentView(R.layout.bnw_dialog);

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - setTitle");
       setTitle("BtnNoWorky");

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - setText");
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(MESSAGE1);

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - setImageResource");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - Instantiate btnCopyNext");
        btnCopyNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnCopyNext);
        btnCopyNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - Instantiate btnNext");
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnNext);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - Instantiate btnQuit");
        btnQuit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnQuit);
        btnQuit.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Log.d(MY_LABEL, "onCreateDialog - Returning...");


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        action = v.getId() ;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                , "Button " + action + " clicked."
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(MY_LABEL, "Button " + action + " clicked.");
        dismiss();
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Good catch, @Idistic, but apparently that's not the only problem.  I do appreciate the response, and now I believe I'm one step closer.  Thanks.

Comment: So in an effort to determine if this was a Service problem or something else, I broke out the problem Activity into an ultra-simple standalone application, which suffers the same fate.  But now I can share... the complete Eclipse project is at [link](http://www.lovelady.com/misc/BtnNoWorky.zip), for those who would like to see for themselves.  I would deeply appreciate any assistance, 'cuz I'm not seeing the cause.

Comment: @Dennis Missed that this was a dialog.  Change it to a class and it should work added your code back in to original answer above, it hits the break point

Comment: Sheer elegance in its simplicity!  Thanks so much, from me, and from the wall that's showing signs of hair and redness.  :)

Comment: @Dennis no problem, maybe up vote my answer and accept it?  Nice visual on the head banging by the way